# Big query views have started breaking that used to work flattened repeated fields no longer working

Tags: google-bigquery

"I have a number of views that I have developed all with this basic structure

```
{ 
    "bar": "barvalue",
    "foo":[
        { "nested": "value" },
        { "nested":"value2"}
}
```

so to I have views like below that work

```
select
  bar as bar,
  foo.nested as nested
flatten([table name],foo)
```

But in more complex views have stopped working this week.  With the old error "Failed to save view. Cannot create valid output schema for field member."   rename nested to foo.nested that I used to resolve with flatten. Anyone else seen this ? Any solutions ? I have view loaded with exactly the same syntax that is failing so pretty sure this is a new "feature" "bug"

So I a specific value that fails now is like this

```
    Last modified                     Schema                    Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Labels
 ----------------- ------------------------------------------ ------------ ------------- ------------ --------
  06 Sep 22:23:45   |- description: string                     4            1450
                    |- adminCreated: boolean
                    +- members: record (repeated)
                    |  |- status: string
                    |  |- kind: string
                    |  |- email: string
                    |  |- etag: string
                    |  |- role: string
                    |  |- type: string
                    |  |- id: string
                    +- scanner: record
                    |  |- scanversion: float
                    |- id: string
                    +- aliases: record (repeated)
                    |  |- alias: string
                    +- nonEditableAliases: record (repeated)
                    |  |- alias: string
                    |- kind: string
                    |- name: string
                    |- directMembersCount: string
                    |- etag: string
                    |- email: string
```

and another

```
    Last modified                 Schema                 Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration   Labels
 ----------------- ----------------------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------ --------
  06 Sep 22:23:46   |- displayName: string              11           20361
                    |- name: string
                    |- organizationId: string
                    |- creationTime: string
                    |- lifecycleState: string
                    +- owner: record
                    |  |- directoryCustomerId: string
                    +- bindings: record (repeated)
                    |  |- role: string
                    |  +- members: record (repeated)
                    |  |  |- member: string
                    +- scanner: record
                    |  |- scanversion: float
```

Then a view like this that fails with the error.

```
SELECT
  "groups/"+email AS name,
  g.members.email AS member,
  g.members.role AS role,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(g.members.email,r'.*@(.*)') AS domain
FROM
  FLATTEN([<projectid>:<dataset>.group],members) g
JOIN
 [<projectid>:<dataset>.organization] o
ON
  o.scanner.scanversion = g.scanner.scanversion
```

Comment: works for me! saved successfully view as `SELECT bar as bar, foo.nested as nested FROM flatten([table_name], foo)`

Comment: Will refine example as it's only failing for me on 1 out of 44 views where I do this so something more subtle than I thought. But has just started happening for a view I have had working for months.

Comment: what exactly error message says for that view at the bottom of your question?

Comment: As a recommendation, I'd suggest you start using the [standard version](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) of bigquery instead of legacy.

Comment: Its some old code and not possible to refactor and this just broke out of the blue. The views had been working for months.

Comment: Error message as per the post i "Failed to save view. Cannot create valid output schema for field member." it suggested renaming the role to members.role. Prior to this week if you did not "flatten" it would get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after further trail and error I have found a work around changing view to this works.

```
SELECT
  violation,
  name,
  parent,
  members.role as role,
  members.member as member
FROM (
  SELECT
    "Invalid group member not in %orgdescription% domains" AS violation,
    name,
    parent,
    role AS members.role,
    member AS members.member
  FROM (
    SELECT
      "groups/"+g.email AS name,
      o.name AS parent,
      g.members.role AS role,
      g.members.email AS member,
      REGEXP_EXTRACT(g.members.email,r'.*@(.*)') AS domain
    FROM
      FLATTEN([<projectid>:<dataset>.group],members) g
    JOIN
      [<projectid>:<dataset>.organizationhd] o
    ON
      o.scanner.scanversion = g.scanner.scanversion
    WHERE
      g.members.email IS NOT NULL)
  WHERE
    domain NOT IN('foo.com'))
```